# Ajax request cannot be sent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an error with my ajax request and it cannot be sent, I have others ajax request that works fine, but not this one.

```
jQuery(".bestellen_button").click(function() {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl + "?" + (new Date()).getTime(),
        timeout: 30000,
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            'action': 'login',
            'url': document.URL,
            'block': jQuery(this).attr('id')

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //window.location.replace(data);
            document.body.innerHTML = data
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Look in the Console for the error (F12) is ajaxurl on the same domain as the page making the request?

Comment: in errorThrown and textStatus i have anything, the ajaxurl it's a global wordpress ajax url it's correct "127.0.0.1/wordpress/ajax-admin.php" ..